# What is the derivative of function $g(x,y)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-derivative

Let $g(x,y) = xf_x(x,y) + yf_y(x,y)$

What is $xg_x(x,y)+yg_y(x,y)$?

I have it equal to $$x^2f_{xx}(x,y) + 2xyf_{xy}(x,y) + y^2f_{yy}(x,y) + xf_x(x,y)+yf_y(x,y)$$

Comment: Yes, looks correct to me.

Comment: Ok thanks, assuming the function f(x,y) is homogeneous of degree 2 and f(-1,0)=f(1,0), can it be shown that f$_x$$_x$(0,0) = 2f(1,0). I'm trying to show this but dont know how to proceed from the derivation of g(x,y)?

Comment: Well, in general if (say) $g(x, y)=xf(\frac{x}{y})$ then $xg_{x}+yg_{y}=x\left(xf'(\frac{y}{x}). \frac{-y}{x^{2}}+f(\frac{y}{x})\right)+\frac{xy^{2}}{x}f(\frac{y}{x})=-yf'+xf+yf'=xf=g$, so try an ansatz $g=xf(\frac{y}{x})$.